# Not allowed to read a file for some reason

Tags: permissions

I have these permissions on a file:

```
-rw-r----- 1 root www-data 540 Mar 18 21:12 /etc/phpmyadmin/config-db.php
```

User `vagrant` is a member of group `www-data`:

```
vagrant@precise64:~$ cat /etc/group | grep www-data
www-data:x:33:vagrant
```

Why can't I read the file as `vagrant`?

```
vagrant@precise64:~$ cat /etc/phpmyadmin/config-db.php
cat: /etc/phpmyadmin/config-db.php: Permission denied
```

Comment: Just to be sure, can you check if your membership to the group is enabled via the `groups` command?

Comment: What are the permissions for `/etc/phpmyadmin`? Is some LSM (AppArmor, SELinux) active? Have you just (i.e. after the last login) added the user to the group?

Comment: @Ketan That is probably not going to help as it seems that `group` just accesses `/etc/group`. But the relevant question is: Is the group in the group list of the running process...

Comment: That would be `id`.  `vagrant` needs "x" (yes, *execute*) permission on `etc` and `phpmyadmin` directories to get to the file.

Comment: What is the output of `command ps -p 3070 -o pid,fgroup,supgrp,args`? (`command` is used to avoid aliasing in `bash`)

Comment: @HaukeLaging: I needed to log out and log back in again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Log in again to make the current group membership configuration active. After a process has been created its group membership does not change (at least not by making changes in the account management).